# Tuleap access permission

Tags: permissions, tuleap

I have a problem with the access permission.

I create a tracker station (country, town...) and a tracker contact (phone, localization, tuleap account). Stations have an artifact link with contact to affect people.

I create three groups : user, admin and operating staff to declare permission access for station field.

So I want to display on station report only artifact affected for the Tuleap account login with only field authorized (user/admin/opstaff) and alert people of change.

Problem 1 : I can't update permission access to artifact for assigned people (I can only : permission to all artifact, submitted or affected to groupe). Why ? This option is really useful for me because of another child tracker (anomaly)

Problem 2 : I can't extract from the artifact link the Tuleap account affected.

Solution Problem 2 => Problem 3 : With openlist I can adding Tuleap account but that make redundancies (and I have to insert the same information twice) with the link and I can't make the field "Assigned" on Semantic option (this field is bind with project user).

Solution Problem 3 => Problem 4 : I don't want to create X groups to affect on X artifact and use the access permission affected to group.

Someone have already make something like that maybe more efficient ?

Comment: I don't understance your sentence "Problem 1 : I can't update permission access to artifact for assigned people (I can only : permission to all artifact, submitted or affected to groupe)", maybe an example would be more helpful

Comment: On Permission Tracker I can select option for the access of artifact :
*have access to all artifact
*have access to artifacts they submitted
*have access to artifacts assigned to group
*have access to artifacts submitted by group
*have access to artifacts assigned to or submitted by group
*are admin of the tracker

Why I can't have an option like "have access to artifacts assigned" ?

Answer (score 0):

For problem 2 and 3, there no such feature as of today.

The possibilities are:

- you can make your own reporting system using the REST API to extract the data you need
- you can contribute to tuleap to add the feature you need
- you can look for dedicated development time https://www.tuleap.org/support#professional-support